# Jar game and probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is verbatim from an online assessment for a quant firm.

3 children are playing a game. The game involves four jars that each contain an equal number of marbles of each of six colors: blue, red, yellow, green, orange, and purple. In a single turn, one draws a marble at random from each jar, and the object of the game is to draw four marbles of the same color. The four marbles are then returned to their original jars and the turn ends.

You observe each of the three children play a turn. The first child draws 2 green marbles, 1 blue marble, and 1 red marble. The second child draws 3 red marbles and 1 yellow marble. The third child draws 4 blue marbles (and wins). In expectation, and including this most recent turn, the third child has played $M$ times as many rounds as the second child, and the second child has played $N$ times as many rounds as the first child. Compute $M+N$.

The definitions of $M$ and $N$ are quite obscure. I think they are just odd ratios:
$$M = \frac{P(\text{getting 3 red, 1 yellow})}{P(\text{getting 4 blue})}$$
$$N = \frac{P(\text{getting 2 green, 1 blue, 1 red})}{P(\text{getting 3 red, 1 yellow})}$$

Numbering the jars $1$ to $4$, $P(\text{getting 3 red, 1 yellow}) = \frac{\binom 43}{6^4}$ and $P(\text{getting 4 blue}) = \frac{1}{6^4}$, thus $M=4$.

Similarly $P(\text{getting 2 green, 1 blue, 1 red})= \frac{\binom 42\cdot 2}{6^4}$ (choose jar number for the greens, then jar number for the blue) and $N=3$.

Thus the answer is $7$. Does my interpretation with the ratios make sense ? Are my computations accurate ?

Comment: I have never heard of a "number of rounds in expectation", but your interpretation sounds reasonable to me. The probabilities that you've computed are correct, and the niceness of the resulting answer makes me think you did things correctly.

Comment: The description talks about "turns", not "rounds". Nowhere is a "round" defined. And it evidently doesn't mean "turn", because by the description that would mean $M = N = 1$. I have no clue what they are even asking about. I don't see where your interpretation comes from, but I cannot argue against it either. To me, it is just another entry in the long list of examples of how not to write a math problem.